# one drop down two ids(div id,select id) how to select in selenium webdriver in java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

html

1. false;" href="#"> Choose One 
   class="select2-search-choice-close" style="display:none;"/> 
         Choose One
   Andhra  Pradesh

Comment: i think css creating one more dropdown and hiding original...

Answer (score 0):

You need one id to find an element, use select's id.

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("tx_rm0x0_state"))).selectByVisibleText("Andhra Pradesh");
```

It should work just fine.

Comment: Are there more elements with same id?? Please provide complete html of the select.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code ids are dynamic and may it would change every time on page load.
So it would be better if you can find the element based on tagname:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.tagname("select"))).selectByVisibleText("Andhra Pradesh");
```

or you can also use the xpath to find the element.

Answer (score 0):

Use this 
         new               Select(driver.findElement(By.id("s2id_tx_rm0x0_state")).selectByVisibleText("Andhra Pradesh");

OR Best Solution is:

```
      Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("s2id_tx_rm0x0_state")));
  select.selectByValue("Andhra Pradesh");
```

Enjoy!